# Uploading dataframe to Google BigQuery. Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-datalayer

I'm currently trying to upload my dataframe into Google Big Query, but I keep getting the following error:

```
   RequestException: HTTP request failed: Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.
 ": 2013, "abca": NaN, "abcd
                  ^
```

Is this because Google BQ cannot read 'NaN' values?

I have the following code:

```
   sample_bucket_name = Context.default().project_id 
   sample_bucket_path = 'gs://' + sample_bucket_name
   sample_bucket_object = sample_bucket_path + '/ABC.txt'
```

bigquery_dataset_name = 'ABC'
bigquery_table_name = 'ABC'

```
# Define storage bucket
sample_bucket = storage.Bucket(sample_bucket_name)

# Create storage bucket if it does not exist
if not sample_bucket.exists():
sample_bucket.create()

# Define BigQuery dataset and table
dataset = bq.Dataset(bigquery_dataset_name)
table = bq.Table(bigquery_dataset_name + '.' + 
bigquery_table_name)

# Create BigQuery dataset
if not dataset.exists():
dataset.create()

# Create or overwrite the existing table if it exists
table_schema = bq.Schema.from_data(aas_dataframe)
table.create(schema = table_schema, overwrite = True)

# Write the DataFrame to GCS (Google Cloud Storage)
%storage write --variable simple_dataframe --object 
$sample_bucket_object

# Write the DataFrame to a BigQuery table
table.insert(aas_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-6):

> Numeric values that cannot be represented in the grammar below (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted.

So no, `NaN` is not a valid JSON value for a number.